# Object property returning undefined when using ternary operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, sharepoint

I'm building an object literal and using the if-else shorthand to set the value of one of my properties, but it keeps returning `undefined` and I don't understand why:

```
var cca = cca || {};


var initialization = function () {
    cca = {
        languageCode: _spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage,
        language: (_spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage == 1033) ? "english" : "french",
        englishTitle: "ENGLISH SITE",
        frenchTitle: "FRENCH SITE",
        site_title: (_spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage == 1033) ? cca.englishTitle : cca.frenchTitle,
        page: _spPageContextInfo,
        path: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,
        isGrantSite: function () {
            return _.includes(cca.path, "grants");
        }
    };
};
```

When I evaluate with a break-point the evaluation returns the proper value but it's not getting saved to the property. However, I'm setting another property in a similar way (cca.language) and that's working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time the ternary expression is evaluated, the assignment to `cca` inside the initialization function hasn't happened yet. Thus, `cca.englishTitle` and `cca.frenchTitle` don't yet exist. One solution is to delay that particular property assignment until afterwards:

```
var initialization = function () {
    cca = {
        languageCode: _spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage,
        language: (_spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage == 1033) ? "english" : "french",
        englishTitle: "ENGLISH SITE",
        frenchTitle: "FRENCH SITE",
        page: _spPageContextInfo,
        path: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,
        isGrantSite: function () {
            return _.includes(cca.path, "grants");
        }
    };
    cca.site_title: (_spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage == 1033) ? cca.englishTitle : cca.frenchTitle;
    site_setup();
};
```

As to why the debugger is evaluating the expression to `"ENGLISH SITE"`, that's because the assignment has already completed (you're on to the next statement).

Comment: So essentially i'm calling on them before their initiated?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with promises also. Take a look at this code:

```js
var test = {
    a: 'aaa',
    b: Promise.resolve(test).then(()=>test.b = test.a)    
}

async function show() {
 await test.b;
 console.log(test);
}
show();
```

so you would do:

```js
var cca = cca || {};
   
_spPageContextInfo = { currentLanguage: 1033};

var initialization = function () {
    cca = {
        languageCode: _spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage,
        language: (_spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage == 1033) ? "english" : "french",
        englishTitle: "ENGLISH SITE",
        frenchTitle: "FRENCH SITE",
        site_title: Promise.resolve(cca).then(()=>
            cca.site_title = (_spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage == 1033) ? cca.englishTitle : cca.frenchTitle),
        page: _spPageContextInfo,
        path: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,
        isGrantSite: function () {
            return _.includes(cca.path, "grants");
        }
    };
};

async function show() {
 await cca.site_title;
 console.log(cca);
}
initialization();
show();
```

please understand that the

```
async function show() {
    await cca.site_title;
    console.log(cca);
}
show();
```

part is just for you to be able to see the complete object as it won't be available immediately after the cca declaration due to it's now asynchronous nature.

But as this is resolved in microseconds, you can continue normally with the execution of your code and don't worry about it.